# RPN Calculator Test-First Can't Coerce Nil Into Fixnum

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, null

I keep getting an error when I try to complete the RPN Calculator assignment that is part of test-first's Learn Ruby materials. I get "nil can't be coerced into fixednum"and have trouble getting the "Calculator is empty" error to raise when I do the following rspec test. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
it "fails informatively when there's not enough values stacked away" do
    expect {
      calculator.plus
    }.to raise_error("calculator is empty")    


class RPNCalculator
    attr_accessor :stack

def initialize
@stack = [0]
end

def push(x)
    @stack.push(x)
end
def plus

@stack.push(@stack.pop + @stack.pop)
end

def minus

@stack.push(-@stack.pop + @stack.pop)
end

def divide

denom = @stack.pop
@stack.push(@stack.pop.to_f / denom)
end

def times

@stack.push(@stack.pop * @stack.pop)
end



def value
    @stack.last
end

def pop(x)
    value = @stack.pop(x)
     raise "calculator is empty" if @stack.nil? 
     return value
end 


end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your getting that error because you're trying to add `0` and `nil` within the `plus` method, the `nil` coming from popping an empty stack.

You're not getting the error raised because `@stack` is never going to be `nil`, since you never assign `nil` to it. It will be `empty?` however, which is what you need to check for. You also need to check for that condition *prior* to popping the stack.